# Loop specific Array several times (Bash script)

Tags: arrays, bash, scp

I'm new to this, so I appreciate every new hint. I'm new into scripting and I think I just reached my knowledge, so I need help.

I got the following Situation:

I have an Windows Server and a Oracle Linux Server. The Windows Server has a few directories and there are some files in it. Now the goal is to transfer the files from each directory in its specific directory on the Linux Server. And I would like to automate this process with a bash-script (yes bash script on windows github, with task scheduler).

The Script:

```
#Files im Ordner des lokalen Servers
array=(
  /c/Users/adbls/Documents/HR/*
  /c/Users/adbls/Documents/Abschluss/*
  /c/Users/adbls/Documents/GL/*
)

#Pfad zu Ordner auf Zielserver
array2=(
  /home/sara.blatter/HR/
  /home/sara.blatter/Abschluss/
  /home/sara.blatter/GL/
)


for index in ${!array[*]}; do

        scp "${array[$index]}" $User@$remoteHost:"${array2[$index]}"
#       rm "${array[$index]}"
done
```

Now as an example, if the directory "Abschluss" has got two files, the destination-path-array obviously won't loop the destination-path-array twice and it ends up with the file being in the wrong directory on the linux server. I know scp -r would solve the problem with my wildcard, but I don't want to copy the directory in my destination-directory.

I hope you understood my question; what is the best way to handle this problem?

Greetings Sara

Comment: can't you use `rsync` instead of `scp`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I had the same idea! But since I'm working on windows git-bash it doesn' support "rsync". Or do you now how to import this as a module?

Comment: Is the name similarity of the pathes between the arrays accidental, or systematic? In the latter case, I would loop over `array2` instead of `array1`, and do the globbing (`*`) inside the `scp` command. Also, I would not loop over the array **indexes**, but the array elements. Furthermore, your current _nameref_ expression `${!array[*]}` does not make sense. Did you ever try to run your script with `set -x`?

Comment: Another possibility would be to use Cygwin instead of git-bash, and then do it with `rsync`. This is what I am using.

Comment: @user1934428: `${!array[*]}` isn't a nameref, it expands to the indices of the array (but it should be `"${!array[@]}"`).

Answer (score 0):

Glob characters aren't expanded when quoted. You should almost always use `@` in array references instead of `*`. Variables need to be quoted.

```bash
#Files im Ordner des lokalen Servers
array=(
  /c/Users/adbls/Documents/HR/
  /c/Users/adbls/Documents/Abschluss/
  /c/Users/adbls/Documents/GL/
)

#Pfad zu Ordner auf Zielserver
array2=(
  /home/sara.blatter/HR/
  /home/sara.blatter/Abschluss/
  /home/sara.blatter/GL/
)

for index in "${!array[@]}"; do

        scp "${array[$index]}"/* "$User@$remoteHost:${array2[$index]}"
#       rm "${array[$index]}"/*
done
```